# Web3py - Getting pending TX's?

Tags: web3js, web3.py, python, filters

Is there any way to get pending transaction for a specified address? I can get all pending transactions for current pending block but I can't filter them. I can do:

`txHashPending = w3.eth.filter('pending').get_all_entries()`

But when I do:

`txHashPending = w3.eth.filter({'fromBlock':'pending','toBlock':'pending','address':'My BSC address'}).get_all_entries()`

It returns transactions that have already been confirmed / validated.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Pending txs are not available on most of the public APIs. If you want them [you need to run your own node](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513).

Comment: Seems weird, I can either get all pending transactions or I can get all confirmed transactions by address, surely there’s a way to get all pending transactions by an address

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#filters):

> When creating a new log filter, the filter_params should be a dictionary with the following keys.
>
> > address: string or list of strings, each 20 Bytes - (optional) Contract address or a list of addresses from which logs should originate.

Have you tried `address` instead of `from`?

Comment: That was my mistake, sorry - I meant to say address. I’ve edited it. It still doesn’t work if I use address

Comment: Have you tried get_new_entries() ? https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#web3.utils.filters.Filter.get_new_entries

Comment: Yep I use that, no luck with that though

Answer (score 0):

The filter method you are trying to use there is actually to filter for event logs; that's why is returning already validated information.

> You can learn more about [event filters here](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-newfilter).

To get information about the pending transactions, you will need to inspect each transaction hash, identify the `to` field and match it with the address that you need.

A more efficient way is to use a WebSocket and the subscription method; this will continuously send you a stream of pending transactions you can inspect.

Here is an example of doing that; note that you might need to install the WebSocket module:

> Note that this script uses web3.py V6, and you need both a WebSocket and HTTP endpoints. WSS for the continuous stream of pending transactions, HTTP to get the details.

This script does the following:

- Connects to a BNB node using Websocket and HTTP endpoints
- Calls the eth_subscribe method and receives a continuous stream of pending transactions using the WebSocket.
- Inspect transactions hashes using `get_transaction` on the HTTP endpoint.
- Matches the `to` field with the address you add.
- Prints the data if there is a match.

```py
# Import required libraries
import asyncio
import os
import json
import websockets
from web3 import Web3  
from web3.exceptions import TransactionNotFound

# Replace with your own Ethereum node WebSocket URL
eth_node_ws_url = 'YOUR_WSS_ENDPOINT'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('YOUR_HTTPS_ENDPOINT')) 

# The address you are interested in
target_address = '0x13f4EA83D0bd40E75C8222255bc855a974568Dd4' # Pancake router V3

async def subscribe_to_pending_transactions(ws_url):
    # Continuously try to connect and subscribe
    while True:
        try:
            # Establish a WebSocket connection to the Ethereum node
            async with websockets.connect(ws_url) as websocket:
                # Send a subscription request for new pending transactions
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({
                    "id": 1,
                    "method": "eth_subscribe",
                    "params": [
                        "newPendingTransactions"
                    ],
                    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
                }))

                # Wait for the subscription response and print it
                subscription_response = await websocket.recv()
                print(f'Subscription response: {subscription_response}')

                # Continuously process incoming transaction hashes
                while True:
                    # Receive a transaction hash and parse it as JSON
                    tx_hash = await websocket.recv()
                    tx_hash_data = json.loads(tx_hash)

                    # Print the transaction hash data
                    # Extract the transaction hash
                    tx_hash = tx_hash_data.get('params', {}).get('result')
                    print(f'New pending transaction hash: {tx_hash}')

                    # Try to get tx details
                    try:
                        tx = web3.eth.get_transaction(tx_hash)
                        # Check if the transaction is to the target address
                        if tx['to'] == target_address:
                            print(f'Transaction to {target_address}')
                            print(tx)
                    except TransactionNotFound:
                        print(f'Transaction {tx_hash} not found')

        # If there's an exception (e.g., connection error), attempt to reconnect
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error: {e}')
            print('Reconnecting...')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

# Execute the subscription function
asyncio.run(subscribe_to_pending_transactions(eth_node_ws_url))
```

Just place the address you want to check in `target_address = '0x13f4EA83D0bd40E75C8222255bc855a974568Dd4'` in this case, I'm just using the PancakeSwap V3 router; basically, this script checks for all pending transactions going to the router and prints the details. From here, you can use the data for further analysis.